# Pandas Dataframe select or pluck 1 row when column 1 is unique but columns 0 and 2 are duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe like below:

```
|  0   |  1    |   2  |
|------|-------|------|
| cats | 987   | pink |
| cats | 22    | pink |
| dogs | 37865 | blue |
| dogs | 373   | blue |
| dogs | 387   | blue |
```

I'm trying to clean the data and pluck 1 value from column 1 for each pair from columns 0/2.  Columns 0 & 2 have duplicate values and should only have 1 row in my dataframe.

What I'd like to reduce the above dataframe is to this

```
|  0   |  1    |   2  |
|------|-------|------|
| cats | 987   | pink |
| dogs | 37865 | blue |
```

I've tried selecting unique pairs, but that doesn't really work.

```
df = df.[0,1].unique()
```

Comment: You should try drop_duplicates

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=[0,2])`?